# Sharepoint forms signing using Co-Sign

Tags: cosign-api

how can we sign a sharepoint form using co sign?
Do they create a PDF or some doc of that forms in the back end and then they apply digital signature to it??

Answer (score 1):

CoSign enables to sign list items (this is where SharePoint stores the data that was filled in the form). Is this what you were looking for ?